# Time difference in seconds (as a floating point)

Tags: python, datetime, floating-point

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> t1 = datetime.now()
>>> t2 = datetime.now()
>>> delta = t2 - t1
>>> delta.seconds
7
>>> delta.microseconds
631000
```

Is there any way to get that as 7.631000 ? I can use time module, but I also need that t1 and t2 variables as DateTime objects. So if there is an easy way to do it with datettime, that would be great. Otherwise it'll look ugly:

```
t1 = datetime.now()
_t1 = time.time()
t2 = datetime.now()
diff = time.time() - _t1
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`combined = delta.seconds + delta.microseconds/1E6`

Comment: or combined = delta.seconds + (float(1) / delta.microseconds)

Comment: @pocoa - this is actually an incorrect conversion. 1/time is a rate (Hz) which really doesn't make sense here. this also clearly provides a different result than the accepted answer on which you commented.

Answer (score 50):

for newer version of Python (Python 2.7+ or Python 3+), you can also use the method `total_seconds`:

```
from datetime import datetime
t1 = datetime.now()
t2 = datetime.now()
delta = t2 - t1
print(delta.total_seconds())
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if there is a better way, but:

```
((1000000 * delta.seconds + delta.microseconds) / 1000000.0)
```

or possibly:

```
"%d.%06d"%(delta.seconds,delta.microseconds)
```